# PostgreSQL simple UPDATE error

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple postgresql table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t_s (
    a integer,
    b integer
);
```

If I do a simple update statement `UPDATE t_s SET a=1 WHERE b=1` I get an error:

```
Chyba SQL:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE t_s SET a=1 WHERE b=1)...
                                                  ^

Ve výrazu:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE t_s SET a=1 WHERE b=1) AS sub
```

Is there anything that can go wrong with this statement? I can't see any reason for this error. I use PostgreSQL 9.1.6.

Comment: Your error message shows that you are **NOT** running the `UPDATE` you claim to be running.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) for this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    UPDATE t_s SET a=1 WHERE b=1 RETURNING a
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM cte;
```

Data modifying statements are available as of version 9.1